# Looking for stats on popularity of JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if there's a site that tracks the popularity of the big/various JavaScript libraries?

Answer (score 9):

Click on the "tags" link at the top of the page.

- JQuery: 1970
- Prototype: 135
- Dojo: 71
- Mootools: 39

Those numbers line up with my intuition on the subject; JQuery is dominating.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [unscientific but nonetheless interesting comparison](http://www.google.com.au/trends?q=jquery%2C+dojo%2C+mootools%2C+yui).  It's interesting because it showed Dojo peaked and jQuery is really ascendant, suggesting jQuery has eaten Dojo's market share.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Google Trends as my unscientific gauge as well.

Comment: Might add prototype in there too: http://www.google.com.au/trends?q=jquery%2C+dojo%2C+mootools%2C+yui%2C+prototype&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

Comment: I thought about it but prototype, being an otherwise normal English word, gets too many false positives.

Answer (score 1):

I think now that jQuery is shipping with Visual Studio you're going to see a huge jump in it's popularity.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using Google Trends comes from a comment by none other than John Resig on [Simon Willinson's blog post](http://simonwillison.net/2007/May/16/libraries/) on this topic back in 2007. I tend to agree with him: [Google Trends for the leading libraries](http://www.google.com/trends?q=jquery%2C+%28ext-js%7Cext+js%29%2C+%28yahoo+ui%7Cyui%29%2C+dojo+%28toolkit%7Cjavascript%7Clibrary%7Cframework%29%2C+prototype+%28toolkit%7Cjavascript%7Clibrary%7Cframework%29&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) is a good heuristic. John's original search omitted Ext (and the acronym "yui" for Yahoo UI); my version is merely an update.